# Pushing ruby app to V2 cloud - Error, no such file ruby_versions.yml

Tags: cloud-foundry

(Cross-posted on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vcap-dev/nQfyzZbwb4k))

I have a hand-crafted V2 installation to which I am trying to push a ruby app.  It is correctly identified as a ruby app as it reports that it is "Installing ruby." but then the following is thrown:

```
Installing ruby.
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `initialize': No such file or directory - ruby_versions.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
            from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `open'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in ruby_versions'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:190:in `chdir'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:190:in `block in ruby_versions'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:189:in `ruby_versions'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:235:in `install_ruby'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:77:in `compile'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/bin/compile:11:in `block in <main>'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:84:in `log'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/vendor/ruby/bin/compile:10:in `<main>'
/home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/lib/installer.rb:17:in `compile': Buildpack compilation step failed: (RuntimeError)
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:15:in `block in stage_application'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:11:in `chdir'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:11:in `stage_application'
            from /home/cdavisafc/cloud-fabric/dea_ng/buildpacks/bin/run:10:in `<main>'
```

A bit deeper in the debugging and I find that after looking in the buildpack cache and in the blobstore it tries to curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/ruby_versions.yml.  I think the S3 bucket is accessible as prior attents to get bundler-1.3.2.tgz at that URL seem to have been successful.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Cornelia

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about that particular error, but we do have a fork of the Heroku build pack that might be worth trying instead.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/heroku-buildpack-ruby

So just push the app again, but do it like this;

```
vmc push --buildpack=git://github.com/cloudfoundry/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```